# Can you give a bounty exceeding your total rep?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties

I just saw [this bounty question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332913/help-on-google-web-history) today and I was a bit confused

This states that "**This question has an open bounty worth +400 reputation from Rahul Joshi ending in 7 day**" but [Rahul Joshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/368472/rahul-joshi) only has a reputation of 1

As per the FAQ, it states that

**Slice off anywhere from +50 to +500 of your own hard-earned reputation and attach it to any question as a bounty.** (User does not have 400 rep to slice off)

And

**Users must have at least 75 reputation to offer a bounty.** (User does not have 75 rep)

Does the FAQ not contradict this question or am i missing something here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, what you describe can happen because the bounty is deducted at the *beginning* of the bounty period. So the user in question previously had 401 rep, offered a bounty of 400, and was left with 1 rep.