# Clearly mention the 75 reputation requirement to start a bounty in the help center page on bounties

Tags: feature-request, bounties, privileges, help-center

On all sites, including beta sites and Stack Overflow for Teams sites, all users need at least 75 reputation to gain the privilege to start bounties.

However, this requirement is not clearly mentioned in the [help center page on bounties](/help/bounty). The text on that page, not including any pages it links to, only implies that one needs to have as much rep as the bounty amount (which is true for bounties of 100+ rep). Nowhere is it stated that one needs at least 75 reputation to start a 50-reputation bounty.

This was previously requested at [Please mention in the help screen that bounties require 75 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204118/please-mention-in-the-help-screen-that-bounties-require-75-rep), but a staff member declined to implement it as the page contains a link to the [relevant privilege page](/help/privileges/set-bounties). However, that link is merely titled as "attach [your rep] to any question as a bounty", and doesn't make explicitly clear that 75 reputation is required. This omission just resulted in [confusion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363635/why-cant-i-add-a-bounty-on-my-48-hour-old-question) from a user as to why the bounty option wasn't showing up at 50 rep despite them [claiming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363635/why-cant-i-add-a-bounty-on-my-48-hour-old-question#comment1213319_363635) to have read that help page.

Can it please be added in explicit text to the help center page on bounties that 75 reputation is required to gain the privilege to put bounties? In other words, can the decision to not action the prior request on the grounds that it's mentioned in an (unclear) link please be reconsidered?

Comment: Why do we have information about bounties split among two help pages and an [FAQ page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067) (which in my opinion is far superior to anything in the Help Center)? I don't think duplicating the information in the bounty help page is the lasting solution to the problem, although it would be a reasonable stopgap.

Comment: @ColleenV usually, I see the FAQs here on MSE as a  'further reading' section of the help center pages: they contain much more detailed information, but often those are things you only need to know if you're really interested in the finer details of how things work. As for the two help pages, I do think it's helpful to have one page for people that earned a privilege, and another that can be linked to people that encounter the use of these privileges by others... You don't need to be told *how* to set a bounty if you can't, but you might be interested in knowing what the heck a bounty is.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I agree that the FAQ as a whole should be just a link for more detailed information. What I meant was that it is better organized and better written than the help center pages. I think instead of maintaining partial/duplicate information on two separate pages, privileges pages should be focused on "what is this privilege exactly" and should point to the more detailed help for how to use it, what the requirements are etc. That page should be organized so that it is easy to find answers to specific questions without reading pages of text.

Answer (score 5):

I tried a simple search [`[bounties] 75`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bbounties%5d%2075) and unless I missed something -discounting deleted questions that aren't visible- there are 12 questions asked on meta.se about the minimum rep necessary to start a bounty. In chronological order [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21123), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34733), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36745), [4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71686), [5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100649), [6](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126229), [7](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125973), [8](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197036), [9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185127), [10](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185765), [11](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292245). Including the one yesterday [12](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363635) that likely originated the current feature request.

While this seems to not have caused too many problems adding 1 sentence to the Help Center would correct the omission.

Comment: I imagine a lot of them would have been downvoted to a negative score for lack of research and as such automatically deleted by the Roomba.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog that would also be my guess, but I have no way of verifying it.